# Vite Dev Mode: Cannot access 'usersApi' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, vite

I am getting this error on my react application uses vite, @vitejs/plugin-react.

The method is imported at the top of the file. This is the file I am getting the error.

```
import {getMinimalAsyncStoreState} from "../../../core/redux/reduxUtils";
import {asyncReduxAutomator} from "../../../core/redux/asyncReduxAutomator";
import usersApi from "../../../user/api/usersApi";

const initialState = getMinimalAsyncStoreState<null>(null);

const sendPhoneValidationCodeReduxStateNS = asyncReduxAutomator<undefined, null>(
  "sendPhoneValidationCode",
  usersApi.sendPhoneValidationCode,
  initialState,
  "basic"
);

export default sendPhoneValidationCodeReduxStateNS;
```

Comment: In my case, it was a circular dependency issue. Perhaps you have the same problem here?

Comment: @СтефанВојводић can you explain the circular dependency issue.?

Comment: @RohitKaushal If I remember correctly I had a ConfirmationModal component that imported the useModalComponent hook, and I also had a useConfirmationModal hook in the same file that imported the ConfirmationModal component. So the dependency is ConfirmationModal file -> useModal file (containing both hooks) -> ConfirmationModal. I had to extract the useConfirmationModal to a separate file. 
The new dependency looks like this:
ConfirmationModal -> useModal;
useConfirmationModal -> ConfirmationModal